# jxl setting cell format as percentage format

Tags: java, jxl

jxl formatting Double value as percentage in jxl cell as ( 87.2% say), I tried doing it but my format becomes 8720%, please tell me how to set cell as percentage to display as 87.2% only

Answer (score 1):

You need to divide by 100 because when you use the "%" the api multiples the value for 100 and put the sign "%".

Font:
http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/NumberFormat.html